# Can Visual Studio Mark Instances of a Highlighted Variable/Function in Scroll Bar?

Tags: visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2015, scrollbar

I'm using Visual Studio for the first time and I'm already missing a feature from Eclipse. Namely, when I select a variable or function, Eclipse would put little colored marks all throughout the scroll bar to show me everywhere that variable or function is used. Can Visual Studio do the same thing somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Extension and Updates Manager, there is an extension named "[RockMargin2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=K1tty.RockMargin)" in the online gallery that adds similar functionality.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... doesn't seem to support 2015

Comment: I wasn't actually aware of the extension and updates manager. I've found some other things that almost do what I want by making it far more obvious, but they're not putting the mark on the scrollbar. So I still have to scroll to see them all. Not as good for large files, but luckily my files are small for now.

Comment: "Hmm... doesn't seem to support 2015"  Sure it does; that's what I use/tested it with (2015 Community Edition), and what that screenshot is from.  Search for it/Get it via `Tools -> Extensions and Updates...` within VS itself.

Comment: Ah, the link takes me to an old one which I tried to use and it didn't work. I swear I searched for it in VB as well but it didn't show up. This time, however, it did :-p. Must have typoed it. Looks like this one works. Thanks!